# Start the foreach from beginning

Tags: php, foreach, php-5.3

How to start `foreach` with a new item if condition false.
I have this code :

```
foreach($a_auctions as $auction){
        # get the winner
        if($auction['for_canada'] == 1 && $isFromCanada){
            // another solution to start the foreach with new item (break, exit) ?
            $this->a_returnData[] = array(
                'winner'       => 'pseudo',
                'title'        => 'title',
                'price'        => 200,
            );
        }else{
            $this->a_returnData[] = array(
                'winner'       => 'pseudo',
                'title'        => 'title',
                'price'        => 200,
          );
        }
    }
```

I want in the if to start with the new item of foreach if condition is not true, the idea is to avoid duplication of code. I added a comment.

Comment: would you please update your question with your desired output

Comment: Please update your code also, it's buggy!

Comment: @BunkerBoy I don't want to duplicate the code in the first if...it's possible to add a break or continue?

Comment: If condition is false - don't add `else`-branch

Comment: [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) should do what you need.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for the reset() command! This rewinds the array pointer to the beginning, check out the manual! (link below)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

If you mean to add another element to the start of the array, use array_unshift():

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php